# How to change Gstreamer Path after upgrading to a higher Version on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gstreamer

I'm running Gstreamer 1.14 on Ubuntu 18.04 and want to upgrade it to a newer version, 1.18 or 1.20.
I tried building it manually from github via meson build. So far the installation worked properly but running `gst-launch-1.0 --version` I still get version 1.14.

Thats the Version that came with the Jetpack (4.5) I'm using on my Jetson, Upgrading the Jetpack is unfortunatly not an option.
I followed this instruction:

```
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer.git
cd gstreamer
mkdir build
meson build
cd build
ninja
```

running `gst-env.py` allows me to use the new version of gstreamer in shell. But I can't figure out how to use it systemwide (in Shell and in c code).

Comment: As the support for 18.04 ends next spring, you could plan to upgrade it to use more current versions of your applications. As far as I see, even Focal (20.04) ships v1.20. Nevertheless, this is off-topic on this site, as this does not look related to programming to me

Comment: May be remove distribution package and try meson install build